# Android layout resource retaining old values

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm using a Resource to set some background style of my TextView (specific borders, etc.).
The background color can't be set in the Resource because it may vary according to some rules.

However, any later use of this resource is reusing the last color assigned, even in a completely different Fragment. Looks like the color is being assigned to the Resource, instead of just in the TextView, and reused across the whole application. However, important to note that different TextViews are showing different background colors as intended.

The problem here that any other future use of the resource is using the last color assigned to it instead of the default color set inside the Resource XML file. I don't want to reset it in the code every time I use the resource. Is there any other way?

Resource XML (specialbackground) - note the default background color is white (#FFFFFF):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="7dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

Use in the code (changing the color) - this works as intended:

```
tvText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.specialbackground);
GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable) tvText.getBackground();
gd.setColor(myObj.getColor());
```

Use in the code (where the problem happens (without setting any background color) - it's using whatever last color was defined last time, even in a completely different Fragment):

```
tvText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_border);
```

Comment: can you post an image what it currently looks like

Comment: I believe platform has issues when recycling Drawables not checking if the colour is different than set in the xml

Comment: have you try to clean and run again ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana Yes, same thing. It works for the ones that need different colors. The problem is that, when reusing the resource and not setting a different color, it's using the latest color set, instead of the one specified inside the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mutate()` before setting any value of the drawable.

Source: http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/05/02/drawable-mutations/